# Pandas: delete only specific duplicate column values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to delete duplicate values of email addresses, preserving only the first original value, from a pandas dataframe column. However, not all the cases have email addresses, so they have 'NaN' values. I will need to delete duplicate NaN values based on a different criteria.

For now, I want to preserve all email addresses equal to NaN, as well as a single unique copy of a duplicate email address.

For example, here is what the pandas dataframe looks like:

```
    Email
    email@email.com
    NaN
    NaN
    email@email.com
    test@test.org
```

I want to remove all duplicate email addresses while preserving the NaN values. So, expected result is something like this:

```
     Email
     email@email.com
     NaN
     NaN
     test@test.org
```

The duplicate emails are removed, but the NaN remain. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `duplicated` + `notnull`:

```
m = ~(df.Email.duplicated() & df.Email.notnull())

df[m]
```

```
             Email
0  email@email.com
1              NaN
2              NaN
4    test@test.org
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This seems to recognize the right values, but I am getting "True" and "False" booleans in my column as opposed to removing duplicate email addresses and keeping NaN.

Comment: Are you indexing the DataFrame with the result of the mask?

Answer (score 0):

use `drop_duplicates` with keep='first' which will keep 1 and will drop the other duplicate

```
data.drop_duplicates(subset ="Email", 
                     keep = 'first', inplace = True)
```